# ¿Qué es Monkey Patching?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, poo, lenguaje-agnóstico

He estado navegando por internet y no consigo comprender que es **Monkey paching**.

Al principio pensaba que era exclusivo del lenguaje `Python`, pero parece ser que no es así y nunca antes había escuchado este termino.

Hasta donde he podido saber parece una forma de sobreescribir código, pero no lo he entendido muy bien.

**¿Alguien puede explicarme qué es Monkey Patching? ¿Cómo se usa y qué aplicaciones tiene?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Monkey Patching" es un término no solo usado en Python, también es usado en otros lenguajes de programación como `JavaScript`, `Ruby`, etc...

Lo que quiere decir que **podemos hacer modificaciones en nuestro código a clases y módulos que han sido previamente definidos, en tiempo de ejecución**.

Su uso y aplicaciones son variados, pero básicamente lo que te permite es **añadir funcionalidad existente a clases y a otros módulos** que puede ser útil para el proyecto que estés desarrollando, sin tener que modificar dicho módulo.

Para esto es necesario que el lenguaje que estemos utilizando sea **dinámico**. Para entenderlo bien, voy a poner la respuesta en lenguaje agnóstico y en Python.

## Lenguaje agnóstico

Creo que la mejor forma de explicarlo es con un ejemplo. Supongamos que defino una clase llamada `Persona` que solo tiene el método `información`:

```
clase Persona():
    * constructor(nombre, apellido, edad)

    * método información:
        * retorna nombre, apellido, edad
```

Esta clase `Persona` se encuentra en un módulo, y yo necesito que la persona pueda hacer un saludo. Aplicando **Monkey Patching** puedo redefinir la clase `Persona` en mi propio script, creando el saludo.

```
Creo el método saludo
Persona.saludo = "Hola me llamo (nombre_clase)"
```

De esta forma la clase `Persona` ya podrá saludar, a pesar de que en el sitio donde se encuentra persona, esto **no está definido**.

```
Creo una persona
persona1 = Persona("Andrés", "Garcia", 45)

Puedo ejecutar el método saludo
Persona.saludo
```

**Salida**

```
"Hola me llamo Andrés"
```

Hacer hincapié en que en el módulo que se encuentra `Persona` no se ha inyectado el método `saludo`. Este módulo sigue intacto y **las personas solo tienen la posibilidad de saludar en nuestro script.**

## En Python

Para el ejemplo de Python, podemos escoger cualquier clase ya creada en alguna de sus librerías, por ejemplo voy a usar la librería de fracciones y su clase `Fraction` y voy a consultar un atributo:

```
from fractions import Fraction

f2_5 = Fraction(2, 5)
print(f2_5.devuelve_cuatro)
```

**Salida:**

```
AttributeError: 'Fraction' object has no attribute 'devuelve_cuatro'
```

Como podemos ver la clase `Fraction` no tiene el atributo `devuelve_cuatro` por lo que nos da error, pero yo puedo definirlo mediante **Monkey Patching**:

```
from fractions import Fraction

#Creamos el atributo devuelve_cuatro en la clase 
Fraction.devuelve_cuatro = 4

f2_5 = Fraction(2, 5)
print(f2_5.devuelve_cuatro)
```

**Salida:** `4`

Aquí nos hemos creado el objeto `f2_5` que ya tiene el atributo `devuelve_cuatro`.

Obviamente este ejemplo es bastante tonto, nadie va a querer hacer esto, pero por ejemplo sería interesante mediante **Monkey Patching** implementar en la clase `Fraction`, un método que nos diga si la fracción es entera o no; vamos a hacerlo:

```
from fractions import Fraction

# Introduzco un método booleano que nos dice si una fracción es entera o no
# Toda fracción cuyo denominador es 1, es entera.
Fraction.es_entero = lambda self: self.denominator == 1

f2_5 = Fraction(2, 5)
f64_8 = Fraction(64, 8)
print(f2_5.es_entero())
print(f64_8.es_entero())
```

**Salida:**

```
False
True
```

En el caso concreto de Python hay **una excepción** para los módulos built-in que están escritos en `C` (por ejemplo `random`) y a estos no se les puede aplicar **Monkey Patching** pero sí para todo aquello que esté escrito en puro Python.