# ¿Cómo solucionar TypeError: can't concat str to bytes en pywhatkit?

Tags: python, pywhatkit

Estoy tratando de enviar mensajes de Whatsapp utilizando pywhatkit con el invonveniente de que no me reconoce los acentos. Al tratar de solucionarlo incluyendo `.encode("UTF-8")` me genera el error `TypeError: can't concat str to bytes`.

Código:

```py
import pywhatkit

mensaje= input("ingrese el mensaje que enviara:").encode("UTF-8")

hora= int (input("Ingrese la hora en que enviara el mensaje: "))

minuto= int (input("ingrese el minuto en que enviara el mensaje: "))

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group("ID del grupo",mensaje,hora,minuto)

print("Mensaje Enviado")
```

Comment: Lo que `encode` devuelve es una cadena de bytes  por eso el error. Debes de convertirlo a un string "normal" usando `decode`

Comment: Según [los type hint de pywhatkit](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/blob/9374768b71d7205553d525602c34968550911a0f/pywhatkit/whats.py#L87), el segundo argumento debería de ser una cadena, no un objeto bytes como el que generas con encode. Así que no entiendo por que usas encode en primer lugar.

Answer (score 1):

*Nota*: Estamos lidiando con un [problema xy](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY), por lo que me centraré en el verdadero problema: que pywhatkit escriba letras con tilde.

#### Explicación

En realidad, la razón por la que no acepta tildes no viene de pywhatkit ni de como estás enviando el mensaje (no es un error tuyo). El problema es de pyautogui, que es lo que en el fondo usa pywhatkit para escribir los mensajes.

pyautogui, por desgracia, no escribe tildes. Cualquier letra con tilde es saltada.

#### Solución usando pynput

Instala el módulo pynput:

```
pip install pynput
```

Y agrega esto **antes** de importar pywhatkit:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import pyautogui

# Controller es un objeto de pynput que nos permite controlar el teclado.
# Tomaremos prestado su método tap.
pyautogui.typewrite = Controller().tap
```

Luego, simplemente envía el mensaje como cadena, **sin** `.encode`. pywhatkit espera que el mensaje sea una cadena común y corriente.

Si entiendes como funciona, podrías hacer variantes de la solución usando cualquier otra librería que escriba tildes.

#### Cómo funciona

La idea es importar pyautogui y reemplazar la función `typewrite` (que es la que usa pywhatkit para enviar letras si no se trata de un salto de linea) por una función o método de otro módulo que sí escriba las tildes (en mi ejemplo uso una proveniente del modulo [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)).
Es importante hacer esto antes de importar pywhatkit, ya que si no pywhatkit no usará la función reemplazada, si no la original debido a que cuando "toma" typewrite de pyautogui, el modulo está sin modificar. Si el modulo fuera importado de otra forma, el orden no importaría.

Luego de eso, una vez pywhatkit se importa, cuando intente importar pyautogui, Python NO reimportará el modulo, si no que lo "toma" de un "cache" (los modulos se importan una sola vez). Y cuando obtenga a typewrite, se quedará con nuestra versión de dicha función, ya que está tomando el modulo modificado.

Este enfoque tiene una ventaja extra: cuando quieras usar pyautogui con otro proposito dentro de tu programa, el problema de las tildes estará "solucionado".

Finalmente, estamos haciendo trabajar a Python con un modulo hibrido entre pyautogui y pynput.

Y solucionado sin modificar ningún código fuente, trabajando con objetos vivos!!! Esto se llama [monkey patching](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409452/qu%C3%A9-es-monkey-patching).

#### Por que no usar el monkey patching para que pywhatkit ya no use pyautogui

Hay dos motivos para esto:

- Requeriría muchas lineas de código extra.
- pynput tiene menos funciones que pyautogui. En particular, pynput no puede ubicar imagenes en la pantalla, que es algo que requiere pywhatkit para saber donde está la caja de texto.