# Caracteres especiales con pywhatkit

Tags: python-3.x

Buen día, estoy tratando de enviar un mensaje a un grupo de Whatsapp que contiene caracteres especiales: (ejemplo)

> La inteligencia es lo que usas cuando no sabes qué hacer.
> Jean Piaget
> (1896-1980 Filósofo y psicólogo suizo.)

Pero al momento de enviarlo lo digita así (omite los caracteres especiales):

**La inteligencia es lo que usas cuando no sabes qu hacer.
Jean Piaget
(1896-1980 Filsofo y psiclogo suizo.)**

Pero si lo envio a un numero especifico de celular, lo realiza bien.
Probe antes de enviar el mensaje al grupo en mostrarlo en la consola y ahi si esta con todos los caracteres.

Gracias anticipadamente

Comment: Sin codigo que examinar, no hay respuestas que dar.

Comment: Supongo que, como pywhatkit no puede usar la url para ingresar automáticamente el mensaje, utiliza pyautogui, que no escribe los caracteres especiales. La solución es usar monkey patching para reemplazar la función de pyautogui por una función de un módulo que pueda escribir caracteres especiales: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/545015/158880

Comment: Gracias a Candid Moe y Dante S., me sirvieron sus consejos.