# Setter para atributos de una instancia de otra clase (Atributos anidados)

Tags: python, clase

Buen día,

A modo de ejemplo para reproducir el problema cree dos clases como se muestran a continuación:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = B()
    
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    
    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        print('setter:',v)
        self._value = v
```

La clase `A` tiene una propiedad y un `setter` para el atributo `value`, que a su vez es una instancia de la clase `B`

Cuando creo una instancia de la clase `A` e intento asignar algún valor a `value` es claro que el `value.setter` se ejecutará

```
a = A()
a.value = 5
```

Esto hace que se imprima `setter: 5` tal como debe funcionar (Ignorando que se sobreescribe un entero en el valor de `value` que es una instancia de la clase `B`).

Mi pregunta es, ¿Existe alguna forma de ejecutar el `value.setter` de la clase `A` si intento asignar algún valor al atributo `b` de la clase `B`?

Es decir:

```
a = A()
a.value.b = 5
```

Esto hace que el atributo `b` obtenga el valor `5` pero me gustaría que se ejecutara `value.setter` y que imprima la línea de `print('setter:',v)`, tal vez la salida podría ser algo como `setter: b=5`, la razón es porque en el proyecto real estoy utilizando `opcua` y se necesita hacer un proceso epecial para poder asginar los atributos de la instancia de la clase que se encuentra en `value`.

La clase del proyecto real es así:

```
# Define data types
data_types = {
    'USINT': ua.VariantType.Byte,
    'SINT': ua.VariantType.Byte,
    'UINT': ua.VariantType.UInt16,
    'INT': ua.VariantType.Int16,
    'UDINT': ua.VariantType.UInt32,
    'DINT': ua.VariantType.Int32,
    'BOOL': ua.VariantType.Byte,
    'BYTE': ua.VariantType.Byte,
    'REAL': ua.VariantType.Float,
    'LREAL': ua.VariantType.Double,
    'STRUCT': ua.VariantType.ExtensionObject,
    'STRING':  ua.VariantType.String,
}

# OPCUA node class
class PVNode(object):
    def __init__(self,client,nodeId='',dt=None):
        self.type = data_types[dt]
        self.node = client.get_node(nodeId)
        self._value = self.node.get_data_value().Value.Value
        
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.node.get_data_value().Value.Value
    
    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        dv = ua.DataValue(ua.Variant(v, self.type))
        dv.ServerTimestamp = None
        dv.SourceTimestamp = None
        #self.node.set_value(dv)
        self.node.set_attribute(ua.AttributeIds.Value.Value, dv)
```

Y la utilizo de la siguiente manera:

```
outSTRUCT = PVNode(client,'ns=6;s=::testOPCUA:inSTRUCT', 'STRUCT')
```

No tengo acceso a la clase `self.node.get_data_value().Value.Value`. Esta clase en realidad viene definida por las variables que leo/escribo por `opcua` desde otros dispositivos (PLC's o computadoras industriales) así que para cada variable puede ser una estructura diferente y por eso he estado intentando hacerlo con un `setter` desde la clase que yo hice para el proyecto.

El `setter` ha sido el intento que he hecho pero únicamente funciona bien si creo dos instancias de la misma variable `opcua` y una la utilizo para asignar los valores a la otra, de esta forma:

```
tmpSTRUCT = PVNode(client,'ns=6;s=::testOPCUA:inSTRUCT', 'STRUCT')
outSTRUCT = PVNode(client,'ns=6;s=::testOPCUA:inSTRUCT', 'STRUCT')

# Para la prueba que estoy haciendo yo sé que en la variable de "OPC UA"
# llamada `inSTRUCT` existe un atributo `dummy` y lo siguiente sí funciona
tmpSTRUCT.value.dummy = 5
outSTRUCT.value = tmpSTRUCT.value

# Y lo que me gustaría es poder asignar "dummy" desde outSTRUCT, así
outSTRUCT.value.dummy = 5     # Esto no manda error, pero se ignora ya que el "setter" no se ejecuta y por lo tanto no se escribe el atributo de la variable de "OPC UA"
```

¿Existe alguna forma de ejecutar el `setter` de la clase `PVNode` (O el de la clase `A` en el ejemplo) al intentar asignar algún valor a los atributos de la clase `self.node.get_data_value().Value.Value` (O clase `B` en el ejemplo)?

O ¿Existe alguna forma de poder asignar los valores de la instancia de la clase `self.node.get_data_value().Value.Value` (O clase `B` en el ejemplo) y ejecutar algún método de la clase `PVNode` (O el de la clase `A` en el ejemplo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Por qué no  te funciona

Cuando haces `a.value.b` es necesario para Python resolver primero `a.value`. Eso utiliza el getter de `a` para obtener el valor, que es una instancia de `B`. Seguidamente se utiliza `.b` sobre esa instancia, por lo que en ese caso se estaría ya usando el getter o setter de `B` y no el de A.

Es decir, `a.value.b = 5` no ejecuta nunca el setter de `A` sino en todo caso el setter de B. Por eso no puedes hacer lo que quieres desde el setter de A.

### Solución

Se me ocurre hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

- La clase `A` define `value` como una propiedad, para acceder a su propiedad interna `_value`, la cual es una instancia de `B` (esto es como lo tenías)
- El getter de `A` en cambio no se limita a devolver lo que hay en `_value`, sino que crea una nueva instancia de una clase "especial" creada alrededor de `B`, pero con sus propios getters y setters. A esta clase que controla el acceso a B la llamaré `BControlado`.
- Son los getters y setters de esa clase (`BControlado`) los que controlarán el acceso a la propiedad `b` del objeto `B()`.
- No proporcionamos un setter para `A.value`, lo que impide que lo puedas modificar (evitando el problema de que le asignes un 5 por ejemplo)

Este es el código que implementa esta idea:

```
class B(object):
    # Tu clase B original, cuyo código no es modificado en ningún momento
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0



class BControlado:
  # La nueva clase que "envolverá" a la anterior
  def __init__(self, b):
    # Recibimos una instancia de `B()` y la guardamos
    self._internal_b = b

  # programamos getters y setters para que un intento de acceder
  # a la propiedad b se convierta en un acceso controlado a la
  # propiedad b de la clase interna
  @property
  def b(self):
    print("getter: b")
    return self._internal_b.b

  @b.setter
  def b(self, v):
    print("setter: b", v)
    self._internal_b.b = v



# Ahora la clase A
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # El constructor no varía
    self._value = B()

  @property
  def value(self):
    # Pero el getter para value devuelve una versión "controlada"
    return BControlado(self._value)

  # Y no escribo setter
```

### Demo de uso

```
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a1.value.b
getter: b
0

>>> a2 = A()
>>> a2.value.b
getter: b
0

>>> a1.value.b = 100
setter: b 100

>>> a2.value.b = 200
setter: b 200

>>> a1.value.b
getter: b
100

>>> a2.value.b
getter: b
200
```

Un intento de cambiar `.value` genera una excepción:

```
>>> a1.value = 5
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: Como no pensé en eso?

Comment: Buen día Abulafia, el problema sería que l clase real que ejemplifico con la clase `B` podría tener muchos atributos y arreglos internamente por lo que según entiendo tendría que crear un `BControlado` para cada posible combinación de atributos de `B` o ¿Habría alguna forma de definir dinámicamente `BControlado` para que cada combinación pueda ser utilizada?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato utiliza los dunder methods __getattr__ y __setattr__. Esos justamente sirven para administrar todos los intentos de obtener y establecer cualquier atributo respectivamente.

Comment: Ah ok, eso es justo lo que mencionaba con la adaptación del tercer método que pusiste con el setattr

Comment: Ya veo! En conclusión, una mezcla de las dos soluciones (aunque tiende a usarse la de Abulafia) c:

Comment: @DanteS., Después de varias pruebas creo que este método se apega más a lo que necesito

Comment: Me imaginaba! En fin, me alegro que te dieran una buena solucion!

Answer (score 1):

#### Solución 1: Monkey Patching

La mejor solución que se me ocurre (y algo sucia) es usar [monkey patching](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/409452/158880).

###### Código

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0

class MonkeyPatcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.modified_class = set()

    def modify(self, instance, new_setattr):
        cls = type(instance)

        if(cls not in self.modified_class):
            cls._old_setattr = cls.__setattr__
            cls.__setattr__ = new_setattr
            self.modified_class.add(cls)

class A(object):
    monkey_patcher = MonkeyPatcher()
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = B()
        self.monkey_patcher.modify(self.value, self._setattr_in_b)

    def _setattr_in_b(self, attr, value):
        print("setter:", attr, "=", value)
        self.value._old_setattr(attr, value)

obj = A()
obj.value.hola = "mundo"
```

###### Produce

```
setter: hola = mundo
```

###### Explicación

La idea es crear una clase auxiliar que nos ayudará con el monkey patching. Esta será inicializada con un conjunto vacío (donde guardaremos las clases ya modificadas previamente). Este registro solo es necesario si no tenés la lista de clases a afectar.

Esta clase tiene el método modify, que recibe una instancia de clase y un llamable por el cual reemplazar el método `__setattr__`.
Modify obtiene la clase a la que pertenece la instancia y, si no se encuentra en el conjunto, guarda el viejo `__setattr__` en el atributo `_old_setattr` y reemplaza el original por el callable que le pasamos antes.

Entonces cada vez que se instancie A, utilizamos una instancia de MonkeyPatcher para modificar la clase B, asociamos a su setattr un método de A y agregamos la clase al conjunto. Y listo!

#### Solución 2: Un método especial

Si no te gusta la solución que usa monkey-patching, se me ocurrió una solución mas limpia, pero tiene el defecto de que no se establece el valor del atributo de forma convencional:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = B()

    def setattr_in_b(self, attr, value):
        print("setter:", attr, "=", value)
        setattr(self.value, attr, value)

obj = A()
obj.setattr_in_b("hola", "mundo")
print(obj.value.hola)
```

El plan es que siempre que llamemos a setattr_in_b se haga x acción y luego se establesca el atributo.

#### Solución 3: b_

Podemos modificar el método setattr de la clase A para que cuando el atributo que se intenta establecer comienza con b_, hacer x acción, quitarle el prefijo "b_" y establecer dicho atributo en la clase B.

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = B()

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if(attr.startswith("b_")):
            attr = attr[2:]
            
            print("setter:", attr, "=", value)
            setattr(self.value, attr, value)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(attr, value)

obj = A()
obj.b_hola = "mundo"
print(obj.value.hola)
```

También podrías lograr el mismo objetivo usando propiedades (recomendado si queres que la acción x se ejecute solo cuando se establecen ciertos atributos).

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = B()

    @property
    def b_hola(self):
        return self.value.hola

    @b_hola.setter
    def b_hola(self, value):
        print("setter:", "hola", "=", value)
        self.value.hola = value

obj = A()
obj.b_hola = "mundo"
print(obj.value.hola)
```

---

Solo por curiosidad, podrías contarme a que solución recurriste???

Comment: Gracias Dante, voy a probar con las tres opciones y te comento (Voy a probar con simulación, pero voy a trabajar con la máquina real hasta el martes), pero se me ocurrió una adaptación del tercer método qué tal vez podría funcionar.

Comment: De nada c: Espero que sirva. Sin embargo, la forma de Abulafia parece ser mejor.