# Cómo desactivo el teclado usando en python

Tags: python, tkinter, os

> Hola, Estoy intentando hacer un programa en el que necesito desactivar
> el teclado con un botón en Python. Este es el código:

```
from os import *
from tkinter import *

#OBJETO VENTANA
wn = Tk()
wn.geometry("500x500+735+200")
wn.resizable(0, 0)
wn.title("Program")

#VARIABLES
state_txt = "Hola!"

#CODE
state = Label(wn,text=state_txt, font=("Arial", 24, "bold"), pady=200).pack()


#LOOP VENTANA
wn.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es todo lo que he investigado.

Comment: Dos cosas. Primero, podrías agregar lo que intentaste/investigaste hasta ahora por favor? Lectura recomendada [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/). Segundo, a que te refieres con "desactivar el teclado". No creo que sea bueno que un programa desactive una forma de interacción entre el software y el usuario. O te refieres a desactivar la posibilidad de usar el teclado dentro de tu propio programa?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Entiendo que "te la sude", pero seguramente si te era importante aumentar tus posibilidades de recibir respuestas, que tu pregunta no termine cerrada y evitar que los votos negativos hagan que el sistema te bloquee de hacer preguntas automaticamente. Yo quería ayudarte en ese sentido. De todos modos, lo que dijiste no responde exactamente mi pregunta. Querés desactivar el teclado en su totalidad, o solo que no se pueda usar el teclado dentro de tus ventanas?

Comment: Lo que si, el titulo de esa respuesta de meta es engañoso, no quiere decir que no intentaste nada, si no que no nos lo demuestras que lo intentaste.

Comment: Solo dentro de la ventana, en cuanto a los puntos vale vota como te apetezca ya me crearé otra cuenta.

Comment: Espero te lo permitan, de cualquier modo, yo no te voté negativo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta original (para deshabilidar el teclado dentro del propio tkinter)

Esta respuesta no es lo que el OP buscaba, pero la dejaré ya que pienso que podría ser util para otros lectores.
Esto se debe a que en esta repuesta solo se deshabilita la capacidad de Tkinter de procesar los eventos de teclado.

#### Solución

Se que no es la mejor solución, pero tampoco encontré nada ni siquiera en los sitios en inglés que responda tu duda.
Entonces tuve que pensar mi solución. Y, aunque no me agrada al 100%, usé una tecnica llamada Monkey Patching para lograrlo.

```
import tkinter as tk

class KeyDisabler:
    """
    Esto debe crearse luego de la ventana raiz (tk.Tk) y antes de crear cualquier widget.
    """

    def __init__(self, v, name="_keylocker"):
        self.original_init = tk.BaseWidget.__init__
        tk.BaseWidget.__init__ = self.widget_init
        self.name = name

        v.bindtags((self.name,) + v.bindtags())
        v.bind_class(name, "<Key>", self.callback)
        self.disabled = False

    def widget_init(self, widget, *args, **kwargs):
        self.original_init(widget, *args, **kwargs)
        widget.bindtags((self.name,) + widget.bindtags())

    def callback(self, event):
        if(self.disabled):
            return "break"
    
v = tk.Tk()

keydis = KeyDisabler(v)

e = tk.Entry(v)
e.pack()

keydis.disabled = True
v.mainloop()
```

Simplemente, para desactivar el teclado, hay que establecer el atributo disabled a True.

#### Conceptos

Para entender la solución, tendrás que tener en cuenta algunos conceptos, podré a continuación algunos links para familiarizarte (si se caen, seguramente haya algo en google sobre el tema):

- [Monkey Patching](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/409453/158880)
- [Como tkinter procesa los eventos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11542200/12913664)
- [Herencia](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/algoritmos-python/capitulo-15/herencia)

#### Explicación del Código

Revisando [el código fuente de Tkinter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dd53b79de0ea98af6a11481217a961daef4e9774/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py), podemos saber que todo widget y toplevel, no asi con la ventana raiz, deriva de BaseWidget y usan su constructor (método `__init__`), incluyendo los widgets de ttk (comprobado con ttk.Entry y ttk.Treeview). En realidad, estoy asumiendolo, pues son muchas lineas de código para mirar, pero es por sentido común, asi que estoy seguro (quien quiera traernos una prueba, bienvenido sea).

Todo esto significa que podemos aplicar Monkey Patching sobre widgetbase para reemplazar su constructor por nuestra versión, la cual se encargará de añadir un "bind tag" al principio de todo para que toda función. Esto se ejecutará en todos los widgets creados después (de ahí la importancia de cuando instanciar esta clase).

`__init__` realiza los siguientes pasos importantes:

- Guarda el constructor de WidgetBase original
- Reemplaza el constructor de WidgetBase por el método "widget_init"
- Agrega al principio de los "bind tags" de la ventana raiz nuestro tag restrictor por las razones antes mencionadas.
- Hace que tkinter llame al método callback cada vez que nuestro tag restrictor recibe un evento "", que es el generado al presionar una tecla.

`widget_init`, que es llamado cada vez que se instancia un widget

- Executa el constructor original con los argumentos pasados a la función (excepto el primero, que es la instancia de KeyDisabler)
- Agrega al widget al principio de todo nuestro tag restrictor

`callback`, que es llamado cada vez que el tag restrictor recibe el evento "".

- Si el atributo disabled es True, devuelve "break", que significa "no sigas pasando este evento a los demás tags"

#### Una alternativa más simple

Si no te gusta esta solución, existe una alternativa más simple, pero que requiere más código repetitivo, mas dificil de mantener, más propenso a errores u olvidos y tendrá que ser mantenido si es que se agregan nuevos widgets:

```
def agregar_restrictor(widget):
    widget.bindtags(("_keylocker",) + widget.bindtags())

widget1 = ...
agregar_restrictor(widget1)

widget2 = ...
agregar_restrictor(widget2)

...

v.bind_class(name, "<Key>", lambda e:"break")
```

---

## Nueva respuesta (desactivar eventos globales mientras la interfaz está enfocada)

Si queremos bloquear el teclado en su totalidad a nivel global, no podemos usar solo tkinter, si no también un modulo multiplataforma que interactúe con el sistema operativo. En este caso usaré [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/). Mi solución está construida en base a [una respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67759903/12913664). Dejaré un ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable del código usado allí por si el link se cae (el original también bloquea el mouse):

```
import keyboard

def blockinput_start():
    for i in range(150):
        keyboard.block_key(i)

def blockinput_stop():
    for i in range(150):
        keyboard.unblock_key(i)
```

#### Solución

Se me ocurrió hacer que en los eventos:

- `<FocusIn>` (el widget/ventana es enfocado) se bloqueé todo el teclado.
- `<FocusOut>` (el widget/ventana pierde el foco) se desbloquee el teclado.
- `<Destroy>` (el widget/ventana está por ser eliminado) se desbloquee el teclado si es que estaba bloqueado. Esto es para evitar que el teclado quede bloqueado luego de cerrar la ventana.
- El cierre forzado del programa (ejemplo "el programa no responde, desea cerrarlo?", "si") se desbloquee el teclado si es que estaba bloqueado (esto lo hacemos usando un modulo llamado signal). Esto es muy importante, no vamos a querer que el teclado del usuario se quede bloqueado luego de un cierre forzado.

Estas políticas aplicadas tanto a la ventana principal como a los toplevels (ventanas secundarias).

A continuación, el script donde hice las pruebas:

```
import keyboard
import signal

class KeyBlocker:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.locked = False
        v.bind("<FocusIn>", self.on_focus_in)
        v.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)
        v.bind("<Destroy>", self.on_focus_out)
        v.bind_class("Toplevel", "<FocusIn>", self.on_focus_in)
        v.bind_class("Toplevel", "<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)
        v.bind_class("Toplevel", "<Destroy>", self.on_focus_out)

        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.on_focus_out)

    def on_focus_in(self, event):
        self.lock()
    
    def on_focus_out(self, event):
        self.unlock()

    def lock(self):
        if(not self.locked):
            for i in range(150):
                keyboard.block_key(i)
            self.locked = True

    def unlock(self):
        if(self.locked):
            for i in range(150):
                keyboard.unblock_key(i)
            self.locked = False
    
import tkinter as tk

v = tk.Tk()

tk.Entry().pack()

v2 = tk.Toplevel()
tk.Entry(v2).pack()

kb = KeyBlocker(v)

def trabador(event):
    while True:
        pass

trabar_al_cerrar = False

if(trabar_al_cerrar):
    v.bind("<Destroy>", trabador)
v.mainloop()
```

En este caso, se puede instanciar esta clase en donde quieras (siempre y cuando la ventana principal esté creada, claro).

Comment: Muchas gracias :D

Comment: De nada! Me alegro haber ayudado. Sin embargo, he notado que aceptaste mi respuesta y volví a mirar y le quitaste la tilde. Encontraste algún fallo o algo no te sirvió?

Comment: Si, el programa funciona pero, no desactiva todo el teclado, la tecla de Windows y las funciones siguen funcionando, sabes algún modo para desactivarlo todo, si no no pasa nada.

Comment: Ahhh entiendo, lo que yo hice fue desactivar el teclado solo dentro de tu ventana. El resto del sistema operativo sigue recibiendo eventos de teclado. Si encuentro una forma, editaré la respuesta. Gracias por decirme!

Comment: Listo! Decidí dejar la versión original de la respuesta por si sirve a un lector futuro. Ojalá te sirva :D