# ¿Es instanciable una clase abstracta en Python?

Tags: python, clase-abstracta

Estoy probando las clases abstractas en Python (3.x). Quiero crear una clase abstracta que indique una serie de métodos que han de ser definidos en las subclases que hereden de esta. No quiero que la clase abstracta sea instanciable, pero en la siguiente prueba sí me deja instanciar objetos de clases abstractas. ¿Alguien sabe por qué? No me entero muy bien con lo que se explica en https://docs.python.org/dev/library/abc.html.

```
import abc

class A(abc.ABC):
   pass

class B(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
   pass


class C:
   __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

   @abc.abstractmethod
   def metodo(self): pass

   @abc.abstractproperty
   def nombre(self): pass



a = A()
b = B()
c = C()

print(a,'||', type(a))
print(b,'||', type(b))
print(c,'||', type(c))


class D(C):
   def metodo(self):
      print(self.__class__)



d = D()
d.metodo()
```

Esperaba que no se pudieran instanciar objetos de clases abstractas; esperaba algún error o excepción. Además la clase D no implementa todo lo que C indica que es abstracto y también se puede instanciar.

Comment: Te han dado una respuesta completa, así que no voy a entrar en detalles. La clase `A` es abstracta, pero sin ningún método definido que suplantar. Las clases `B` y `C` son _helpers_ para crear clases abstractas, pero no son _per sé_ clases abstractas. Sí que lo serán las que deriven de ellas, como la clase `D`. Si pones el decorador `@abstractmethod` a algún método y creas subclases verás que ahí sí funciona todo como esperas.

Answer (score 1):

#### Metaclases

El modulo abc usa, en el fondo, una metaclase. Una metaclase define el tipo de una clase, la metaclase default es type. Con ello se puede personalizar, por ejemplo, que pasa cuando se le asigna un atributo a la clase misma, en lugar de a su instancia.

Es decir, este código:

```
class a(metaclass=b):
   pass

a.hola = "mundo"
```

Es equivalente a

```
class a(metaclass=b):
    pass

b.__setattr__(a, "hola", "mundo")
```

#### Los modulos y su diseño

A veces, verás que los modulos no se fijan por el uso correcto de sus caracteristicas, eso lo dejan en manos del desarrollador. Pasa sobre todo con librerías de terceros.

Por ejemplo, si tenés un método que está diseñado para aceptar un entero, no se revisa que ese entero proporcione las caracteristicas necesarias para aplicar el [duck typing](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Digamos que siempre "asume que es un pato".

#### Por que se puede instanciar abc.ABC?

Ahora, sabiendo todo esto, vamos a tu pregunta. Primero que nada, debemos saber que toda clase cuya metaclase derive de type, por default, se puede instanciar.

Cuando se intenta instanciar una clase, en realidad la estas llamando, por lo que se llama al método magico `__call__` de la metaclase.

Si miramos el [código fuente de abc](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/abc.py) (dejo la parte relevante por si se cae el link):

```
class ABCMeta(type):
    """Metaclass for defining Abstract Base Classes (ABCs).
    Use this metaclass to create an ABC.  An ABC can be subclassed
    directly, and then acts as a mix-in class.  You can also register
    unrelated concrete classes (even built-in classes) and unrelated
    ABCs as 'virtual subclasses' -- these and their descendants will
    be considered subclasses of the registering ABC by the built-in
    issubclass() function, but the registering ABC won't show up in
    their MRO (Method Resolution Order) nor will method
    implementations defined by the registering ABC be callable (not
    even via super()).
    """
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, /, **kwargs):
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
        _abc_init(cls)
        return cls

    def register(cls, subclass):
        """Register a virtual subclass of an ABC.
        Returns the subclass, to allow usage as a class decorator.
        """
        return _abc_register(cls, subclass)

    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
        return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)

    def __subclasscheck__(cls, subclass):
        """Override for issubclass(subclass, cls)."""
        return _abc_subclasscheck(cls, subclass)

    def _dump_registry(cls, file=None):
        """Debug helper to print the ABC registry."""
        print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
        print(f"Inv. counter: {get_cache_token()}", file=file)
        (_abc_registry, _abc_cache, _abc_negative_cache,
         _abc_negative_cache_version) = _get_dump(cls)
        print(f"_abc_registry: {_abc_registry!r}", file=file)
        print(f"_abc_cache: {_abc_cache!r}", file=file)
        print(f"_abc_negative_cache: {_abc_negative_cache!r}", file=file)
        print(f"_abc_negative_cache_version: {_abc_negative_cache_version!r}",
              file=file)

    def _abc_registry_clear(cls):
        """Clear the registry (for debugging or testing)."""
        _reset_registry(cls)

    def _abc_caches_clear(cls):
        """Clear the caches (for debugging or testing)."""
        _reset_caches(cls)
```

Veremos que no se "sobreescribe" `__call__`, lo cual nos permite instanciarla.

#### Por que te deja instanciar una clase "incompleta"?

Bueno, en este caso, mis pruebas indican que no estás haciendolo de la manera en el que el módulo está diseñado. En este caso, te diría que Python ni se da cuenta que C es una clase abstracta.

Si lo haces de la forma esperada, usando la clase ABC:

```
import abc

class C(abc.ABC):
   @abc.abstractmethod
   def metodo(self): pass

   @abc.abstractproperty
   def nombre(self): pass

class D(C):
   def metodo(self):
      print(self.__class__)
```

Instanciar D produce el siguiente error:

```
Can't instantiate abstract class D with abstract methods nombre
```

#### Adquiriendo el comportamiento deseado.

Todo esto, significa que si queremos que nos de error al intentar instanciar una clase abstracta, deberemos programarlo nosotros:

```
import abc

class ABCMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
       if(ABC in cls.__bases__ or cls is ABC):
            raise NotImplementedError("No se puede instanciar una clase abstracta.")
        return abc.ABCMeta.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    
class ABC(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass
```

En este código, creamos una metaclase derivada de abc.ABCMeta. Luego, reemplazamos el método `__call__` y averiguamos si la clase es directamente derivada de ABC `ABC in cls.__bases__` o de hecho ES ABC. Si se cumple esta condición, producimos un NotImplementedError.

**importante**

- Con este diseño, hacer `class a(metaclass=ABCMeta)` NO HACE LO MISMO que `class a(ABC)`. De hecho, deberías de usar lo segundo. Esto se debe a que mi código se basa en revisar las superclases y así determina si se trata o no de una clase abstracta. Por lo que es requisito necesario que la clase abstracta derive de ABC para que funcione.
- Te recomiendo no aplicar [monkey patching](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409452/qu%C3%A9-es-monkey-patching), ya que este código funciona ligeramente distinto al modulo abc y eso podría interferir con la funcionalidad de otros modulos que usan clases abstractas.