# ¿Uso de random.randint() en python para un rango inespecífico o infinito?

Tags: python, random

Estoy trabajando con el modulo `random.randint` para crear una lista de `n` números enteros.

La sintaxis me obliga a introducir un número mínimo y uno máximo para el rango de random.

```py
rand = random.randint(a, b)
```

¿Habría una forma de que ese rango fuera indeterminado o infinito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desconozco cuál es el propósito de necesitar un número entero aleatorio *infinito*. Pero hay un límite en la memoria de los ordenadores para conseguir representar números enteros gigantescos.

Por ejemplo, un [gúgol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BAgol) se define como `gugol = 10**100` (un 1 seguido de 100 ceros), un número grande, pero manejable (pero no lo uses como límite en bucle). Si seguimos, definimos *gúgolplex* como `10**gugol`, equivalente a `10**10**100`. Su creador, Kasner, lo definió como *«un uno, seguido de ceros hasta que te canses de escribir»*. No te aconsejo que lo pruebes en python. Pero se puede ir más allá para definir *gúgolduplex* como `10**gugolplex`, o sea, `10**10**10**100`, para lo que no hay máquina ni tiempo en todo el universo para representarlo. Y aún así estamos hablando de números pequeños en comparación con el [número de Graham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_de_Graham).

Volviendo al funcionamiento de los números pseudoaleatorios de python, según pone en la documentación del [módulo random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1.

Aquí está indicando que la máxima precisión que puedes esperar conseguir del generador de números aleatorios es de 2**19937-1, que es un entero de unos 6000 dígitos. Muy inferior a un gúgolplex.

¿Quiere decir que no se pueden generar números aleatorios más grandes? Es posible, basta con llamar varias veces a la función generadora.

Como demostración, vamos a hacer una función que genere números enteros de longitud arbitraria, llamando a la función generadora por cada uno de los dígitos:

```py
from random import randint

def rand_digit() -> int:
    return randint(0,9)

def rand_plex(size: int) -> str:
    return "".join(str(rand_digit()) for _ in range(size))

# un entero aleatorio de 100 dígitos
print(rand_plex(100))
```

El resultado lo saca como `string` para poder verlo mejor ya que en python3 hay limitación para ver números enteros de más de 4300 dígitos. Supongo que no es problema adaptarlo a lo que necesites, aunque sería mejor buscar alternativas más eficientes que llamar al generador aleatorio para cada dígito.

Answer (score 1):

##### Existe una forma?

No existe una forma proporcionada directamente por el modulo random. En cambio, se puede hacer lo siguiente:

- Usar [monkey patching](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409452/qu%C3%A9-es-monkey-patching) o modificar el módulo con la forma de hacerlo.
- Utilizar un número muy grande (ejemplo, 10 ** 12, 10 seguido de 12 ceros) para aumentar las posibilidades del rango

##### Por que podría ser imposible o inconveniente.

Piensalo así. Si el rango fuera infinito en alguno de sus dos lados, ¿de cuantas cifras debe ser el número obtenido? puede ser un 10 seguido de 100 ceros? o mil? O lo que dé la memoria del dispositivo?

Usar infinito o número grande aumenta las posibilidades de obtener números ridiculamente grandes del estilo que verías en quimica.

**Pseudoaleatorios, no aleatorios**

No se mucho de numeros pseudoaleatorios, pero te diré lo que se. Invito a cualquiera a mejorar la respuesta con más información.

Una maquina no puede simplemente "pensar en un número", si no que utiliza un número inicial llamado semilla y lo va aplicando a una formula que va dando numeros que **aparentan** ser aleatorios.
Y si, si se elige siempre la misma semilla, los números generados son los mismos. De ahí que se pueda crear un mundo especifico con una semilla en el videojuego Minecraft.

Esa formula, que no he encontrado/entendido, podría requerir números finitos para funcionar correctamente.

##### Una alternativa

En lugar de indicar un número especifico, indica el número de cifras que deseas que tenga ese número. La formula para obtener el número más grande que se puede formar con n cifras es:

```
(10 ** n) - 1
```

Que por ejemplo para 3 cifras devuelve `999`.

Eso se lo pasas a random.randrange para no tener que restar 1 y te queda, para números positivos de 3 cifras:

```
random.randrange(0, 10 ** 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias.
Era solo saber si se podria prescindir de alguna forma del rango min-max.
Gracias a los dos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: De nada! Pero la proxima usa comentarios para comunicar esas cosas